# How would I be able to check how far apart two characters are?

Tags: python

Say I have two characters (in this case "S" and "E") and an unknown amount of characters in between them, how would I work it out? For example: turning "SmcfjfE" into "S-----E"

Comment: Do they have to be in order? As in, does S have to come before E?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You could replace any character except "S" and "E" with "-", if I understand correctly.

Comment: That is certainly going to depend on several factors including the format of your input data and what you need to do with the output.  Please take the time to prepare a clear concise question that includes a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted along with a clear description of what is wrong with your current effort.

Comment: What should `S-E-S----E` return?

Comment: `len(mystring) - 2`?

Comment: @KellyBundy That only works in this case (i.e if the characters of interest are at the start and end of the string)

Comment: @Ben Quote: *"I have two characters [...] and an unknown amount of characters in **between** them"*.

Comment: @KellyBundy In this particular case/example yes, but the question is "how would I be able to check how far apart two characters are?", which implies no stipulation that these characters are at the start and end. Finding the difference between the character indices (with str.index) is far more appropriate.

Comment: @Ben No, that just looks like they're being brief in the title because that's not the place to put all the details. And in the question body they clarify that they're the start and end. In any case, note that I put a question mark after it, asking whether that interpretation of the question is indeed correct. And if they hadn't abandoned their question, we might know the answer by now.

Comment: @KellyBundy My point is that ```len(string) - 2 ``` is a hack that works for this particular case but, whilst it works for the singular example given, it does not address the question as a whole (also, they don't explicitly specify that the characters are that the start and end). Take a look at the answers provided. If someone else were to have a similar question and came to this page, using string indices would be by far the preferable advice as it addresses more use cases that reasonably fall under this question.

Comment: @Ben It's not a hack. And I guess I could repeat the quote, which does specify that they're the start and end, but you'd probably just keep interpreting it differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the difference between their index provided they are the first occurences of the letter in the string. To handle cases where the letters are in the opposite order you can take the absolute value. For example:

```
string = "SmcfjfE"
diff = abs(string.index("E") - string.index("S"))
print(diff)
```

Comment: If order didn't matter and E could come before S, you could wrap the calculation for diff in abs(), which would return the absolute difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the str.index() function for this, e.g.:

```
'SMILE'.index('E') - 'SMILE'.index('S')
```

However, S and E need to be unique in the string.